# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot register after unregistered Filter class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am developing login service using spring boo. when developing it I got below error and the class

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot register after unregistered Filter class com.jwt.logincservice.filter.JwtFilter

```
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private Jwtutil jwtUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
        }


        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigureAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myUseserDeatailService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUseserDeatailService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authentication").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, JwtFilter.class).authorizeRequests();
    }


    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have an implementation of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, could you add it?

Comment: @pero_hero  i add the class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you are trying to add the `jwtRequestFilter` before the `JwtFilter.class` which is kind of telling spring security to put itself before itself.

can you try changing this line to:

```
http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).authorizeRequests();
```

additionally, every `Filter` bean in spring boot is automatically added also to your default servlet filter chain, so after initialization, it will be present twice:

1. as a Servlet Filter in your chain
2. as a Filter in your springSecurityFilterChain

if you just want to use it as a spring security filter remove the `@Component` annotation and instantiate it by yourself before adding it to the springSecurityFilterChain:

```
http.addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).authorizeRequests();
```

Comment: @Component annotation is what go me.  Thanks.  #dontDoubleUp

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java config for bean configuration you have to register your filter bean in WebInitializer class.

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    //your configs

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        DelegatingFilterProxy filterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
        filterProxy.setTargetBeanName("jwtFilter");
        return new Filter[]{filterProxy};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The list of filters to put in the *class part can be retrieved by increasing the debug level on spring security. Any filters there will work.